# P(A ∪ (B ∩ C) | C) = P(A ∪ B)?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to compute the probability of `P(A ∪ (B ∩ C) | C)`.

The following probabilities are given:

```
P(A) = 0.01
P(B) = 0.04
P(C) = 0.05
```

This is the solution:

```
P(A ∪ (B ∩ C) | C)
= P(A ∪ B | C)
= P(A ∪ B)
= 1 – 0.99 x 0.96 = 0.0496
```

Could someone explain this solution to me? Specifically how C gets eliminated and why `P(A ∪ B)` results in `1 – 0.99 x 0.96`.

Thanks!

EDIT: A, B and C are independent events.

Comment: Use the definition of conditional probability

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 I'm so sorry about that... would you mind rewriting your answer with independency in mind? I know P(A|B)=P(A) but I don't get how P(A ∪ (B ∩ C) | C) turns into P(A ∪ B | C).

Comment: How it turns is shown below, I only used the definition and basic set properties such as $(A\cup B) \cap C=(A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)$ and $(B\cap C)\cap C=B\cap C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the first equality, it follows from $P(A\cup (B\cap C)|C)=\frac{P((A\cup (B\cap C))\cap C)}{P(C)}=\frac{P((A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C))}{P(C)}=\frac{P((A\cup B)\cap C)}{P(C)}=P(A\cup B|C)$.

Since $A,B,C$ are independent, $A\cup B$ and $C$ are also indepenent and therefore $P(A\cup B|C)=P(A\cup B)$ (it's the basis property of conditional probabilities).

As for the result, it cannot be true, since $P(A\cup B)\ge P(B)=0.4$.

Comment: What do you mean it cannot be true? They're asking for the probability...

Comment: It stays above. $P(A\cup B)$ cannot be smaller than $P(B)$.

Comment: Could you maybe explain how they came up with P(A ∪ B) = 1 – 0.99 x 0.96 = 0.0496?

Comment: It looks like the usage of the formula $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. But the numbers are wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I get it now. Btw, I believe P(A U B) results in P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B) = 0.0496 so P(A∪B) is bigger than P(B). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's still no way that $P(A\cup B)=0.0496$ if $P(B)=0.4$.

Comment: Why not? P(A) is only 0.01, while P(B) = 0.04, it makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: I see above that $P(B)=0.4$, not $0.04$.